# Why model.getProperty("field") returns null while model.oData.field has value?

Tags: sapui5

As a newbie in SAPUI5, I'm aware I'm doing something wrong but still couldn't identify what.Simple situation I have.

The `JSONModel` instance loads by `controller.onInit()` without an issue. The view works as expected, showing bound data from model, etc. But in the controller code in a certain button press event method, the following code prints `null`:

```
console.log(oItem.getModel("site").getProperty("id"), oItem.getModel("site").oData.id);
```

output:

```
null 10
```

As you see, data is loaded correctly, as `10` is the value I expected, but `.getProperty()` doesn't return it.

What is wrong in my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call getProperty as follows:

`oItem.getModel("site").getProperty("/id")`

Please check the [documentation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/d52e364907f94a3caeb4f5e5ad0cf302.html) to get an idea how the binding syntax works. Without the leading slash your binding path is relative and requires a binding context which you did not provide.